# Change MainView of app based on Setting.bundle toggle switch state?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, settings.bundle

I am trying to change my mainView of my app based on the toggle switch state in the setting.bundle. The default I want set to NO, which I have set. But it seems I missing something, the only way I can seem to get the view to change with my code is to change the default value. I am doing this in the delegate.m file in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Please any help would be great!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

//Registers the defaults.
NSUserDefaults *metricDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[metricDefaults registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"metric_preferences"]];
BOOL metricDisabled = [metricDefaults boolForKey:@"metric_preference"];
[metricDefaults synchronize];

//Change MainView based on Metric setting.
if (metricDisabled) {

    //Standard View.
    MainViewController *aController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
    self.mainViewController = aController;
    [aController release];

    mainViewController.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    [window addSubview:[mainViewController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

} else {

    //Metric View.
    MainViewController *aController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewMetric" bundle:nil];
    self.mainViewController = aController;
    [aController release];

    mainViewController.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    [window addSubview:[mainViewController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

}
```

Comment: Why set `[metricDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"metric_preference"];` if you want to _check_ the state of the toggle switch?  get rid of it and run again.

Comment: Tried that too, if I get rid of that line, it will only load MainView, and never loads MainViewMetric no matter the state of the toggle switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use registerDefaults: to set the default for this key to NO.  This gives a value to the user default if it's never been set by the user, but doesn't affect what value it has after a user changes it.  The way you're doing it, always sets the user default value to NO.

After Edit:

This is the way you do that:

```
NSUserDefaults *metricDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [metricDefaults registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"metric_preferences"]];
    BOOL metricDisabled = [metricDefaults boolForKey:@"metric_preference"];
    [metricDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: If I set it to YES or NO as default, when running the app, the toggle switch is always on, I want the default to NO, and when NO I want the MainView to show. When it's set to YES, I want the MainViewMetric to show.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem.  Do you want the value of that user default to be NO when the app is first run, and then YES or NO depending on what the user changes it to on subsequent runs?

Comment: Sorry, I am wanting the default value of the toggle switch in the settings.bundle to be NO by default. Then if users decide they want Metric, they can set it to YES in the settings, then when they relaunch the app, it loads the MainViewMetric, not the MainView(Which is the standard). Hope that clears up what I'm needing. (Yes, what you said sounds like what I'm wanting to do.)

Comment: Yes that does. So have you tried using registerDefaults:?  There's no way to do what you want without doing that (that I know of anyway).  See my edited answer for how to do this.

Comment: I was researching how to register the defaults, sorry I'm still pretty new. Thanks for supplying the example, but the toggle switch in the settings still shows on by default, and doesn't change the view still weather I change it to on or off. Is there something in Xcode 4 to "tell" the app I have added a settings.bundle? I read that somewhere, but the directions were for an older version of xcode.

Comment: What do you mean by "the settings still shows on by default".  How are you determining that?  By which view loads? And, how are you changing it to on or off?  You don't show that code.

Comment: So if I run the app, it shows the MainView, I close the app and go to the settings where the toggle switch is, it should show off by default, it doesn't. Weather I change the toggle switch from on to off doesn't change the view that loads when reloading the app.(I edited the code above to reflect what I have now.)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it was backwards.

Comment: I just switched where I had the if and Else, and that worked! Awesome!! Thank you so Much! I learn much faster when I can see it work!

Comment: My app is crashing now when loading the second MainView. Was wondering if I could send you the error I'm getting?

Comment: It's too long to send on here...is there an email through this site?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MainViewController 0x8982cd0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key metricPicker.'

Comment: If you want to send me the code you can send it to rdelmar@comcast.net